# How to load image and make it as background in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I just want to ask a simple question, how do I load an image and make it as a background in my html5 canvas

```js
var bg;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600,400)
  bg = loadImage("https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/1/92/T1iecJ.jpg")
}

function draw() {
  background(bg)
}
```

i tried that method but the screen only showing whitescreen, i've search for it but i can't get the solution.

Answer (score 6):

[`loadImage`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage) doesn't load an image `synchronously`. The image may not be immediately available for rendering.

Use the [`preload()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload) function, to ensure that the image is load before [`draw()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw) is executed. [`setup`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/setup) will wait until any load calls within `preload()` have finished.

```js
var bg;

function preload(){
    bg = loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/background.jpg")
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600,400)
}

function draw() {
    background(bg)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: the page only shows loading, and the image isn't coming out

Comment: @DevenValisten Then the image path is wrong or you don't have access to it.

Comment: @DevenValisten The image is not allowed to be load: *"Access to image at 'https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/1/92/T1iecJ.jpg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*"